# Sum of rational functions with exponent

Tags: analysis

How to compute 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{K}\frac{P(j)}{Q(j)}\exp(2\pi ija) $$
where $\left|a\right|<1,\ K\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\frac{P(j)}{Q(j)}$ is a rational function and the roots $Q(j)$ are known, complex.$$$$

In my case 
$$Q(j)=(1+j^{2q})(j^{2p}+(j-A)^{2p})$$
with integer $q,p>0$  and real $A>=0$.

$$P(j)=(j-A)^{2p}$$ or $$P(j)=j^{2p}$$ or $$P(j)=j^{2}(j-A)^{2p}$$

Comment: Numerically?$\,$

Comment: Why $|a|<1$? But $K$ should be positive, presumably?

Comment: J.M   not numerically,but but some approximation mistake is ok

Comment: Didier Piau, K is positive, integer. $\left|a\right|<1$ in my case. I don't know if it is helpful

Comment: My idea is to approximate the sum with integral, use partial fraction decomposition, and try to express it with exponential integrals. Don't know if its going to work

Comment: So you want an (approximate?) analytic expression for your sum, then?

Comment: yes. At least approximate expression

Comment: Are the roots of $Q(j)$ distributed everywhere in the complex plane or are the in the upper half-plane, or ...?

Comment: everywhere, but they have a nice form (I have edited my question)

Comment: What is $x$ doing in the definition of $Q(j)$?

Comment: @Katja: If $Q(j)$ is so simple, maybe $P(j)$ can also be provided in the question? And yes: what is $x$?

Comment: Your rational function certainly will have a complicated partial fraction decomposition...

Comment: I can deal with partial fraction decomposition. But it seems that approximation by integral doesn't work :(

Comment: This type of problem is dealt with in Melzak "Concrete Mathematics" chapter 3 section 5.  It does involve a partial fraction expansion and a couple of tricks to get to a digamma/dilogarithm form.